# How to read data from Real time database firebase using flutter with a complicated JSON tree

Tags: json, firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, read-data

I am working on a flutter app and I found obstacles on how to read product_name and price from Firebase and display them in list

[image]

I tried this code but it returns the whole JSON tree as a Text

```
    class _BeveragesProductsState extends State<BeveragesProducts> {
  var _firebaseRef = FirebaseDatabase().reference().child('Products');

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(' Beverages Products'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: StreamBuilder(
              stream: _firebaseRef.onValue,
              builder: (context, snap) {
                if (snap.hasData &&
                    !snap.hasError &&
                    snap.data.snapshot.value != null) {
                  Map data = snap.data.snapshot.value;
                  List item = [];
                  print("data $data");
                  data.forEach(
                      (index, data) => item.add({"key": index, ...data}));
                  print(item);
                  return ListView.builder(
                      reverse: true,
                      itemCount: item.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Text("$data"),
                          ],
                        );
                      });
                }
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRTVm.jpg)

Comment: Do you have access to the id under `Products`?

Comment: @PeterHaddad no I don't have access to it but I will need it later is there a way to read data like this   var _firebaseRef = FirebaseDatabase().reference().child('Products').child(key).child(Beverages).child(id)? I really need it

Comment: Is key equal to the id inside the database?

Comment: @PeterHaddad no its just an example I mean "_firebaseRef = FirebaseDatabase().reference().child('Products').child(key).child(Beverages).child(id)"

Comment: thats result of print(item) [{key: q13uw8NqeBgxJ3hrLeyxKL4VjV22, Beverages: {-METQIa_vyKFXoLWE9xf: {Product_price: 105, Product_name: pepsi}}}] and this is the result of print(data) data {q13uw8NqeBgxJ3hrLeyxKL4VjV22: {Beverages: {-METQIa_vyKFXoLWE9xf: {Product_price: 105, Product_name: pepsi}}}}